# Help to determine what type of encryption has been used?

Tags: encryption

I am performing a security assessment against an application, i would like to recognize the encryption function used to generate the following hash

PWYXFYNRWTYZ
HVZPVPMBBFPB
VXTCHXMHPKVH

As shown above, the hashs are 12 byte alphabets

Regards

Comment: If you are performing assessment, you should have access to the source code and you should analyze the algorithm, not the results. It seems neither you nor your boss nor your customer understand that.

Comment: I know of no hash employing only consonants (and the probability of not there being even one vowel in 36 letters is vanishingly small - some 4.5E-4). You should give some more information on how the hash is generated and why are you sure it is a hash at all.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear whether each of the three values that you posted is a result of the hash function in question, or the result of the hash function is all three values concatenated together.

However, it looks like the each of the values that you posted are 55 bits long.  Each of them are made of 12 English uppercase letters.  There are 26 uppercase letters in the English alphabet, so this means that there are 2.54*10^16 (26^12 = 2.54*10^16) possible such combinations.  The equivalent number of bits needed to produce this number of combinations is 55 (2^55 = 3.60*10^16).

Most modern hash functions produce results that are much longer than 55 bits in length (e.g. even the obsolete MD5 hash function produces 128-bit results).  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hash_functions, which shows the length of the results produced by various hash functions.  So, my guess is that the result of the hash function in question is all three of the values that you posted concatenated together.

If that's the case, then this means the result is 165 bits in length (55*3=165).  So, it's possible that this could be RIPEMD-160 (160 bits) or MD5 (128 bits), or several others referenced at the link above.

Comment: Hello mti,  the strings are not concatenated together, each one represent a hash result.  I found a interesting informations, each hash is related to timestimp of account creation. 

PWYXFYNRWTYZ 1567372064
HVZPVPMBBFPB  1567374207
VXTCHXMHPKVH 1567374806

But i can't figure out the hash algorithm

Comment: In that case, each result is only 55 bits long, at most.  Not enough for any modern hashing algorithm.  Also, it's a very unusual encoding method.